# How to pass data to urllib3 POST request method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib3

I want to use `urllib3` library for making POST request over `requests` library since it has connection pooling and retries etc. But I couldn't 
find any substitute of following `POST` request.

```
import requests
result = requests.post("http://myhost:8000/api/v1/edges", json={'node_id1':"VLTTKeV-ixhcGgq53", 'node_id2':"VLTTKeV-ixhcGgq51", 'type': 1 })
```

This is working fine with `requests` library but I couldn't convert this into `urllib3` request.
I tried

```
import json
import urllib3
urllib3.PoolManager().request("POST","http://myhost:8000/api/v1/edges", body=json.dumps(dict(json={'node_id1':"VLTTKeV-ixhcGgq53", 'node_id2':"VLTTKeV-ixhcGgq51", 'type': 1 })))
```

Problem is with passing raw json data with `json` as key in `POST` request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the `json` keyword argument; you are wrapping your dictionary in another dictionary there.

You'll also need to add a `Content-Type` header, set it to `application/json`:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
data = {'node_id1': "VLTTKeV-ixhcGgq53", 'node_id2': "VLTTKeV-ixhcGgq51", 'type': 1})
r = http.request(
    "POST", "http://myhost:8000/api/v1/edges", 
    body=json.dumps(data),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```